# Loop through directory, open workbook, print selected worksheets

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I have about 50 workbooks that have 3 worksheets, and I need to print the first 2. The names of the worksheets will be constant so this shouldn't be too hard.

I wrote the following in VBA and it doesn't error out but my printer doesn't print anything. What am I missing?

```
Sub Loop2()
    Dim StrFile As String
    Dim WSCount As Integer
    Dim sh As Worksheet

    StrFile = Dir("c:\temp\*.xls*")
    Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
        Debug.Print StrFile
        StrFile = Dir

        For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

           If (sh.Name <> "Credits") Then

               sh.PrintOut

           End If
        Next sh
    Loop
End Sub
```

If I use a `MsgBox` as scaffolding I do get the files and their worksheets, but no printing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two problems

1. Where are you opening the workbook?
2. You need to move `StrFile = Dir` just before the `Loop`. With this command you are telling it to find the next file.

Try this (**UNTESTED**)

```
Sub Loop2()
    Dim StrFile As String
    Dim WSCount As Integer
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook

    StrFile = Dir("c:\temp\*.xls*")

    Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open("c:\temp\" & StrFile)

        For Each sh In wb.Worksheets
            If (sh.Name <> "Credits") Then
                sh.PrintOut
                DoEvents
            End If
        Next sh

        wb.Close (False)
        StrFile = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

And if you want to print the first 2 sheets as mentioned in your question then do this. This will not check the name of the worksheets

```
Sub Loop2()
    Dim StrFile As String
    Dim WSCount As Integer
    Dim wb As Workbook

    StrFile = Dir("c:\temp\*.xls*")

    Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open("c:\temp\" & StrFile)

        wb.Sheets(1).PrintOut
        DoEvents
        wb.Sheets(2).PrintOut

        wb.Close (False)
        StrFile = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! I forgot about opening the files. Rather obvious, really. I'm new to VBA, I'm more of a Python guy. Thanks!

Comment: In this case It's not a good practice to use the _Sheets.Index_, since you already know the name of the Sheets to print I suggest to use their Names instead of the index. Create an array with the names and For Next the array

Comment: @EEM: I gave the 2nd option and mentioned what it does. Since OP said "first 2 sheets", I gave that as an alternative :)

Comment: User also mentioned: _"The names of the worksheets will be constant so this shouldn't be too hard."_

Comment: @EEM: Tru and hence the first option :)